Nextjs: import alias not working in route group
I am experimenting with route groups and nested layout files when every import using "@" threw module-not-found
jsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@lib/*": ["lib/*"],
      "@app/*": ["app/*"]
    }
  }
}

This is the error I am getting
⨯ ./src/app/(main)/dashboard/page.js:9:1
Module not found: Can't resolve '@lib/schemas/subscriptionSchema'
   7 | import NotAccepted from "./notAccepted";
   8 |
>  9 | import Subscription from "@lib/schemas/subscriptionSchema";
     | ^
  10 | import Users from "@/lib/schemas/userSchema";
  11 | import Events from "@/lib/schemas/eventSchema";
  12 | import Stripe from "stripe";

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Folder structure:

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks
Nextjs version 14.2.3
Tried replacing @/ with ../../ (however many was necessary) ...it worked, but is not a viable option.

I had the same problem with my application after updating the dependencies, which was working fine before.
I then just removed '@' wherever it was, and it works.
For example, where I had imported a components like this import AComponent from "@/components/a-component", I replaced it with import AComponent from "/components/a-component" without the @ symbol and it works.
Admittedly my jsconfig.json file is a bit different from yours, mine only contains this bit of instructions:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "paths": {
    "@/*": ["./*"]
  }
}

}
So far, the only solution that has worked for me is this one, hoping it will help you.
